# Critical push notifications on Android

Tags: android, push-notification

In ios I can program critical push notifications that even when the device I s on silent it will make a sound. You need approval from Apple but this is working fine.

Is such thing also possible on Android devices? And how is this called
and could you refer me to some documentation or having an example?

I can only find high prio message but that doesn't seem to do the job.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Probably this answer could help you - [play sound in android notifications although phone silent mode is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664657/play-sound-in-android-notifications-although-phone-silent-mode-is-set)

Comment: Thank you I will take a look